# issue with One Page Scroll plugin in Rails 4 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, purejs-onepage-scroll

I'm having this weird issue with a button in my Rails 4 app. I'm using the One Page Scroll plugin.

To scroll to a section, when a button got clicked, I implemented this jQuery code:

```
  $(".project").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".main").moveDown();
    $(".main").moveDown();
  });
```

the markup for my button element looks like this:

```
<button class="project">Ontdek het project</button>
```

However, the button get only clickable when the page got a scroll event. When I load the page the button is not clickable.

I implemented the onepage_scroll method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: "section", 
    easing: "ease",
    animationTime: 1000,
    pagination: true,
    updateURL: false
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if this issue is caused by Rails turbolinks or if something else is causing this issue.

Any help or suggestions are very welcome.

greetings,

Anthony

Comment: Have you tried using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead? It seems people solve those problems using the `destroy` function it provides: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues?q=rails

Comment: Hi Alvaro, yeah, I switched back to fullPage.js Seems that my problems with fullPage.js where css-related. Everything is working now.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more? So I can know what the problem was for future queries about this same problem?

Comment: I created an issue about this on the fullPage.js github repository: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/986 .Another issue I had was that not all my pages are using fullPage.js, but the fullPage.js css was giving all pages a postion: fixed attribute. I could work around this by putting the fullPage.css styles in a page style tag.